# В чем ошибка при создании связей (belongs_to) в ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems

Есть две модели - Blog и Post.

**blog.rb:**

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post
end
```

**post.rb:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :blog
end
```

**Далее файлы ActiveAdmin:**

**admin/blog.rb:**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Blog do
    permit_params do
        allowed = [
            :title,
            :description
        ]
        permitted = *allowed
        permitted << :other if params[:action] == 'create' && current_user.is_admin?
        permitted
    end
end
```

**admin/post.rb:**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
    belongs_to :blog
end
```

Делал все по этому мануалу: http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#belongs-to

**В результате получаю ошибку:** https://habrastorage.org/files/bd9/2b7/0f6/bd92b70f6ed741ceb871ca59987bf5d4.png

Я перегуглил все что мог. Нигде ничего нету.
Добавить записи в Blog могу. Проблема только со связями - на странице: */admin/blogs/5/posts*.

В чем проблема? Я ничего сверхъестественного не делал. Все по образцу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один блог имеет много пост**ов**

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
end
```

Вместо

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :post
end
```

Comment: Я был уверен на 100%, что проверял этот вариант... Но тем не менее - вы мой герой!